# Can i run the pom file of sub directory after completion of all phases of parent directory pom?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have below multi module maven project

```
MyProj
  -Api
    -pom.xml
  -Impl
    -pom.xml
  -pom.xml
```

After replacing few tags and code using maven replacer plugin, I'm copying the Api & Impl module under another directory

```
MyProj
  -Api
    -pom.xml
  -Impl
    -pom.xml
  -pom.xml
  -PublicDir
      -Api
        -pom.xml
      -Impl
        -pom.xml
      -pom.xml
```

I want to create artifact for all four project (changed and unchanged) I'm having trouble in compiling the source which is generated under PublicDir from the parent pom ( \MyProject\pom.xml). Is there any way to handle this scenario ? Will build-helper-maven-plugin plugin help in this ? I added this plugin and pointed to generated source location, but couldn't get the desired result.

or in simple word - can i run the other MyProj/publicDir/pom.xml after completion of all phases of MyProj/pom.xml ?

Here is the pom -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sample.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>impl</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Some dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>regex</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>api/**/*.*</include>
                                <include>impl/**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <token>@Start.*?@End</token>
                            <value></value>
                            <regexFlags>
                                <regexFlag>DOTALL</regexFlag>
                            </regexFlags>
                            <outputDir>/publicDir</outputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- some more plugin -->
        </plugins>
</project>
```

Comment: That seems backwards to me; normally a top-level project would depend on a child project, not the other way around.

Comment: In fact i want to run it from top project only, i could have added PublicDir as module but problem is that PublicDir is getting generated at run time and if i add it as module, i will get error in validation phase itself.

Comment: Can you give the pom here to what's going on?

Comment: I just added pom details. replacer plugin creates a new director and copies both modules. I'm at \MyProj\pom.xml and want to build the project which is copied and replaced.

Comment: If you generate PublicDir than it should be put under the target folder from which it is generated from and not put into a different location....Can you give more details what you are generating ?

Comment: I want to have two type of artifact, one for internal users and other for external users, external users will have limited amount of code which i'm restricting by having annotation Start, End  tag across multiple java file. \MyProj\pom.xml is for internal users and while running this pom, using replacer plugin, i'm generating code for external user (limited APIs/code) under PublicDir folder. Now along with source code, i need artifact as well (jar files), I could get the source code but now how can i run the pom of PublicDir from \MyProj\pom.xml.